# How to extract data from perl hash if a subkey could be a value

Tags: perl, hash

I am extracting data and the resulting hash can be one of two examples:

```
$VAR1 = {
          'calculated_at' => '2015-09-01T03:27:11.528Z',
          'result' => {
                        'previous' => 0,
                        'now' => 71
                      }
        };
$VAR1 = {
          'calculated_at' => '2015-09-01T03:27:11.624Z',
          'result' => 342
        };
```

If example1 , the value should be 71, else it should be 342.

I have tried:
`if (exists $jhash{result}{now}) { print "Test\n";}`

But that breaks on the second example:
`Can't use string ("341") as a HASH ref while "strict refs" in use`

What is the proper way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `ref` to see if result is a reference.  [perldoc ref](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/ref.html)

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use warnings;
use strict;

my $results_data = [
    {
          'calculated_at' => '2015-09-01T03:27:11.528Z',
          'result' => {
                        'previous' => 0,
                        'now' => 71
          }
    },
    {
          'calculated_at' => '2015-09-01T03:27:11.624Z',
          'result' => 342
    },
];

for my $data (@$results_data) {
    my $result = ref $data->{result} ? $data->{result}->{now} : $data->{result};
    print "Result is $result\n";
}
```

**Output:**

```
Result is 71
Result is 342
```